# Why can I not find .cs files in Temporary ASP.NET Files as VS2012 recommends me so to do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am using MVC3,C#, .NET4, VS2012.

I am trying to work out an assembly reference error, the causal file of which, according to VS2012, is:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4ce30959\16e34b5\App_Web_orders.cshtml.b7021bbc.0.cs
```

But it does not seem to exist. There is nothing named like the above, and the others have ".compiled" or ".dll" extensions. So completely baffled.

The error is:

```
Error   51  The type or namespace name 'Document' does not exist in the namespace 'Orders.MVC3.' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4ce30959\16e34b5\App_Web_orders.cshtml.b7021bbc.0.cs 36  0   Orders.MVC3
```

So how can I find App_Web_orders.cshtml.b7021bbc.0.cs?

Yes I have tried searching for it on my hard drive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, your previous question would have the same response as this one.  You're changing your models and not updating the views accordingly in some instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your messages, you have turned on `compile views` or you are precompling your site within your MVC project.  This error is misleading, because as part of that compiling the views, it creates these fake and strangely named files when it compiles them.  If you look closely at the error, its telling you that there is a View called `Orders.cshtml`.  Your model for this view appears to be `Orders.MVC3.Document` which does not exist.  So, you either moved, renamed, refactored or deleted that model which is causing this view's model to no longer be found.

Comment: What is strange about this is that "Orders.cshtml" is not used by the current application, and is not referenced in the ".csproj", although having searched my hard drive I see that I did use it in a previous version of the application and it does exist on a drop box drive and in the .csproj on the same archive drive. So it is an old reference, and it seems something somewhere is still trying to reference it. It is excluded and deleted from the current project. So baffled. So something is causing the precompiler to find this old cshtml file, quite what I am unsure...

Comment: I have just found the offending view in my current application, but it is "excluded" from the project. I found it after a windows explorer file search. So I have selected "show all files" in VS2012 and deleted it entirely. I thought "Exclusion" would exclude the file from any reference within the project??

Comment: Typically it should, but maybe it was cached in the obj/debug or release folder.  I usually don't exclude views so I can't speak to why it was still being found.  I would recommend that you use source control and delete things when you don't need them any longer.  If you need it back, use your source control to go get it :)

Comment: Again, @Tommy well observed on one of my to do tasks ie SC !!! Slightly off topic, but which SC are you using Git, SubV or ??

Comment: @SamJolly   I use mercurial with bitbucket.  Free for up to 5 users, https://bitbucket.org

Comment: Thanks..Really appreciated. I think I am on the move now, going through a load of old excluded files. Also it is interesting how many little Razor errors appears when you do this precompile step. It is almost as if the rebuild/JIT thing is too forgiving....

Comment: Is Mercurial simpler than GIT?

Comment: @SamJolly - I think they are about the same to me, just started using Mercurial first.  Try both and see which one you like better!  As for the rebuild, look into setting the compile views option to true.  By default, the compiler does not compile views unless you precompile or tell it to using the `MvcBuildViews` option in the project configuration file